# Can other processes run during memory paging?

Tags: multithreading, memory, multiprocessing, virtual-memory

First off, take a single processor system with multiple processes running in pseudo-parallel. When a process triggers a page fault, will this force the CPU to stop executing all programs until the page is loaded from disk?

If so, does this change on a multi-core or multiprocessor system, or can the other processes continue to read and write to memory while the page fault is dealt with?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very OS dependent question.  Please specify what OS and version you are talking about.

Comment: I had Linux in mind, but if it works differently across operating systems, I would be interested to hear about the differences.

Comment: @Gray: Theoretically, perhaps, but this capability dates back to middle of the last century. E.g. IBM OS/360.

Comment: This page provides a good level of detail, and some crazy colors to boot - http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/355/Syllabus/9-virtual-mem/page-fault.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, scheduling does not work for processes but for threads. A page fault only suspends the thread incurring the fault (on Linux and Windows). The thread is descheduled and the CPU is free to do other work.

At the level of the OS interfacing hardware there is no synchronous IO anyway. It does not exist (at least with modern hardware). The OS does not sit in a tight spin-loop waiting for the hardware to signal IO completion. Instead, the thread is descheduled until the IO completed (or the respective wait handle becomes signaled).

Comment: Your OS model is true for modern harddisks which use DMA. But historically IDE used PIO, programmed I/O which required permanent OS attention until the IO completed. And at the hardware level, there really is no **asynchronous** IO anyway. There's a DMA or PIC-e bus controller doing all the synchronous IO, and it will report the completion asynchronously to the CPU. Still a benefit since that's a simple dedicated controller which is tied up, not an entire CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is not a problem at all. Nobody in their right mind designs a multi-process OS that's unable to run multiple processes, nor would they arbitrarily block process A because B is waiting on a disk I/O.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I know that as of a couple of years back a select on disk IO would _always_ say it was ready.  That implies to me that the Linux kernel might not be able to schedule a disk IO request in the background.  Or maybe it would work with SSA but not with SATA.

Comment: Looking up  I/O led me to Wikipedia's articles on Asynchronous I/O and DMA, which confirms what you're describing.

Comment: @Gray: So? The Linux kernel keeps a list of _runnable_ processes. Issuing a disk I/O may take one process off that list, but the question implies that the entire runnable process list is cleared. That's utterly pointless. Async I/O and DMA have nothing to do with this. One process might even be waiting for someone to insert a CD-ROM, without that affecting other processes. Just think about `crond`, that doesn't get stopped on every I/O either.

Comment: I'm just saying that just because the OS/360 did something decades ago doesn't mean that a kernel IO fault in the Linux kernel presents the same environment.  User IO is a different beast from page-faults.

Comment: @Gra: The details may differ, but the question wasn't about details anyway. "User I/O" versus "page fault" is another detail. Both mean that the affected process (thread) cannot run, neither blocks another process from running. Oh, the reason that `select` never seemed to block? It didn't. The previous `read()` had blocked and finished. [Windows can do the same.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/08/10073039.aspx)